# How many subsets of a well ordered set are isomorphic to the whole set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

Could you please help me to solve following problem from an exam.

Suppose $\langle A,\prec \rangle$ is well orderered set whose ordinal is $\alpha$.

What is the cardinal of set of all subsets of $\langle A,\prec \rangle$ that are similar (have the same ordinal) to $\langle A,\prec \rangle$.

My try so far:

If $\alpha$ is finite ordinal, than there exists only one subset of $\langle A,\prec \rangle$ that is similar to $\langle A,\prec \rangle$, $\langle A,\prec \rangle$ itself.

if $\alpha=\omega$ , then $\langle A,\prec \rangle$ is similar to $\langle N,< \rangle$, and there are at least $\aleph_0$ subsets of $\langle N,< \rangle$ that are similar to $\langle N,< \rangle$, for example, set of all natural numbers that are divided by any natural number greater than 1. Can we find more than $\aleph_0$ such sets ?

But how to proceed and form a valid argument about any ordinal $\alpha$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you find a complete characterisation of order type of subsets of $\Bbb N$?

Comment: Every infinite subset of $\omega$ is order-isomorphic to $\omega$. There are continuum-many such subsets.